# Writing Servo pwm in ardupilot

Tags: arduino, pwm

I wrote this code for write PWM in `aux pin0` pixhawk hardware but I couldn't see PWM signal in this pin with oscilloscope.

```
#ifdef USERHOOK_SUPERSLOWLOOP
uint16_t pwm = 2000;
void userhook_SuperSlowLoop()
{
    uint8_t _channel=9;
    pwm = 3000 - pwm;
    hal.rcout->enable_ch(_channel-1);
    hal.rcout->write(_channel-1, pwm);
}
#endif
```

any idea what I do wrong?

thanks